# Hosted webpage on aspspider.com cannot connect to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, connection-string, sql-server-express, shared-hosting

I have windows autentication, if i should change how to change that???

```
 <add name="ConnectionString" 
      connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
            AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;
            Integrated Security=True;
            User Instance=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />


<authorization>
   <allow users="*" />
   <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
```

Comment: Have you copied your database to your hosting space?

Comment: yes the database and the database log file that VS2008 creates

Comment: And has your host attached the database to the instance of SQL Server that you're supposed to connect to? Did your host give you any details about this? They should have given you a server name and SQL auth username and password, which will change your connection string and remove `AttachDbFilename`. I also doubt you'll want to continue using the `User Instance` setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aspspider's own instructions would be the best place to start.

[How to create a new SQL Server database ?](http://www.aspspider.com/tips/Tip16.aspx) - it says here you can't use auto attach, you have to attach it to the server via the Database Manager which I presume you have access to when you log into their management site.

And here are instructions on the connection string you should use:
[Connection strings for MS Access and SQL Server Express](http://www.aspspider.com/tips/Tip18.aspx)

Comment: Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=YourUserId_DatabaseName"

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have access to the app-pool to change the user and also the the SQL server to set the permissions I'd just change to standard username/password security.

Take a look at [www.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com) for details on how to do it.

You will then need to add the relevant user to your database security.